# error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied

Tags: git, ubuntu, git-config

I am relatively new to the Ubuntu OS and Git.

I have installed Git on Ubuntu 20.04 by following the instruction mentioned in the following link

[Getting Started Installing Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git)

As mention in the [next step](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup) that there are three levels of Git Configuration

1. **System Level Configuration** - which applies to *every user* and all their repositories on the system
2. **Global Level Configuration** - which applies to the *current user* and all the their repositories on the system
3. **Local Level Configuration** - which applies to the *specific repository* you are working with

I was able to change the global settings of the git by using the --global option, and also change the local setting of the git by using the --local option. But when I tried to change the setting of the git on system level using --system option, I encoutered the following error by the running the command `git config --system user.name "My Name"`

**Error:**
`error: could not lock config file /etc/gitconfig: Permission denied`

Comment: 1. Files under `/etc/` belong to root and must be edited with root privileges. 2. But: you're trying to set you personal configuration in the system config. My advice is: don't do that, use your global user config: `git config --global user.name "My Name"`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Files under `/etc/` belong to root and must be edited with root privileges:

```
sudo git config --system user.name "My Name"
```

But you're trying to set you personal configuration in the system config. My advice is: don't do that, use your global user config:

```
git config --global user.name "My Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, you might have installed git using sudo permissions, in other words as a root user. So .git directory is owned by root user

You can change the ownership to your user like

```
sudo chown -R bitnami:daemon .git/
```

Once `.git` is owned by your user then **you have all the permissions** to config git using `git config comands`.