# Azure static webapps not able to deploy - Failed to remove 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' from the git config

Tags: git, azure, azure-static-web-app

I've tried to put my `github repo` for a `react website` onto the **azure static web apps** - but I keep getting an error trying to deploy it.

```
"Build and Deploy Job Failed to remove 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' from the git config"
```

I don't understand what permissions issue is occuring - as I've authorized the azure and given all workflows read/write permissions.  [image]

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't able to deploy?  I have that error message but it doesn't block deployment for me.  Check elsewhere in your logs to see if there are any other hints.

Comment: I was able to get it working - once I disabled the In the GitHub Action YML file set under CI to false (around line 26). I did/do have a lot of unused imports tripping it up.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you are able to resolve the error by setting **`ci:  false`** in your github action workflow.

**Error 1:-**

```
"Build and Deploy Job Failed to remove 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' from the git config"
```

This error occurs when there's a change in permissions in the github repository. Refer this [**github issue**](https://github.com/aiidalab/aiidalab-test-app-action/issues/1) on the same error.

**Change the permissions in your github action workflow checkout step with `run:  chmod  -R  777  .`**

And the error below occurs due the user not having root privileges. According to this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266149/error-could-not-lock-config-file-etc-gitconfig-permission-denied) by **phd** add the root privileges at the global config level. And by Haijerome is to change the ownership of your .git directory to your user.

**Error 2:-**

```
error: could not lock config file .git/config: Permission denied
```

**Github action workflow:-**

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - name: Set User Configurations
        run: |
          git config --global user.name "Your Name"
          git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"
          chmod -R 777 .  # Change permissions as necessary
      -  name:  Disable  CI  
      - run:  echo  "CI=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_GROUND_09B44C803 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: ""
          output_location: "build"

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_GROUND_09B44C803 }}
          action: "close"
```

*Github action workflow for the change in user's permission in **.git***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - name: Change Ownership of .git Directory
        run: |
          sudo chown -R $USER:$USER .git/
          
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          submodules: true
      -  name:  Disable  CI  
      - run:  echo  "CI=false" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_GROUND_09B44C803 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/"
          api_location: ""
          output_location: "build"

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_AMBITIOUS_GROUND_09B44C803 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]